# Multiple Record picklist to one contact multi picklist

Tags: custom-object, picklist, contact, multi-select

Scenario:

I have one contact "John Doe" who owns multiple and different type properties.  In the property object, each has a "Type" and "Sub-Type".  In the "type" picklist, it includes Drugs stores, banks, etc. (types of commercial business) and in the "Sub-Type" are Walgreens, CVS, Chase etc.

Is it possible to create a Multi-picklist in CONTACT that whatever properties he has will be in the multi-picklist field?

Ex.
John Doe is the owner of Walgreens and Chase back.  So he has two (2) property records.  Property Record 1 "type" says Drug Store with a "sub-type" saying Walgreens.  And Property record 2 "type" says Bank and a "Sub-type" of Chase.

BUT in the *Contact record* itself says... 
Type: Drug Store; Bank &
Sub-Type: Walgreens; Chase

Is this possible?  Can you guide me or show me a sample code that I can mess with?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking you can resolve that via workflow but it seems like you can't update a multi picklist field. So here is a quick code that I wrote on the fly to explain the logic of how this can be achieved. You need to adjust it based on your object/field names and also extend it to check for duplicate properties (I assume you already have a control over creating duplicate properties on the same contact).

```
trigger PropertyTrigger on Property__c (after insert, after update, after delete)
{
    // Find all the parent contact IDs from the property records in the trigger
    Set <Id> contactIds = new Set <Id> ();

    for (Property__c property : trigger.isDelete ? trigger.old : trigger.new)
    {
        contactIds.add(property.Contact__c);
    }

    // Create a map of the parent contact Id and the actual contact record (instantiate via the ID)
    Map <Id, Contact> contactsMap = new Map <Id, Contact> ();

    // Query all property records related to all affected contacts in this trigger
    for (Property__c property : [SELECT Id, Type__c, Sub_Type__c, Contact__c FROM Property__c WHERE Contact__c IN :contactIds])
    {
        // First time, put entry in the map and instantiate the contact record
        if (contactsMap.get(property.Contact__c) == null)
        {
            contactsMap.put(property.Contact__c, new Contact(Id = property.Contact__c));
        }

        // No type on the contact, let's put the type from the first related property
        if (contactsMap.get(property.Contact__c).Type__c == null)
        {
            contactsMap.get(property.Contact__c).Type__c = property.Type__c + ';';
        }
        // The contact has some type set already (from another property), let's append the other property
        // multi picklist values are separated with semi colon
        else
        {
            contactsMap.get(property.Contact__c).Type__c += property.Type__c + ';';
        }

        // Same for sub type
        if (contactsMap.get(property.Contact__c).Sub_Type__c == null)
        {
            contactsMap.get(property.Contact__c).Sub_Type__c = property.Sub_Type__c + ';';
        }
        else
        {
            contactsMap.get(property.Contact__c).Sub_Type__c += property.Sub_Type__c + ';';
        }
    }

    update contactsMap.values();
}
```

Comment: I'm having an issue here

for (Property__c property : [SELECT Id, Type__c, Sub_Type__c, Contact__c FROM Property__c WHERE Contact__c IN :contactIds])

Comment: line 15 it says that...
No such column 'Contact__c' on entity 'Property__c'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

What am I missinfg

Comment: That'd be the name of your lookup relationship to the contact object, I assumed the API names, you need to replace them with your own